# How to create a 'sprint' ability in a 2d game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an ability of sprinting in 2d Unity (C#) that has an energy bar so it can't be used endlessly. What am I missing?

I've tried making sprint a function and call it when the X key was pressed. Tried to multiply the position of it but I got a blinking ability over a short distance.

```
\\ this is my movement script, other variables we're declared earlier in the code

void Update() { 
        Vector2 mi = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        mv = mi.normalized * speed;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + mv * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
```

I expect the code to make the player go twice the normal speed when the X key is pressed but it can only be used when the energy hasn't ran out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see your implementation of "energy" but I would simply use a

```
public float energy;
// How much is energy reduced per second?
public float decreaseSpeed;
```

for increasing the speed if x is pressed do

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector2 mi = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    mv = mi.normalized * speed;

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.X) && energy > 0)
    {
        // Reduce energy by decreaseSpeed per second
        energy -= decreaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        // if needed avoid negative value
        energy = Mathf.Max(0, energy);

        // double the move distance
        mv *= 2;
    }
}
```

Btw ot is recommended to use `Time.deltaTime` instead of `Time.fixedDeltaTime` also in `FixedUpdate` (see [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html))

Comment: Depending on Asker's needs, it might be wise to compare `energy` to  `decreaseSpeed * Time.deltaTime` in order to avoid negative values of `energy`.

Comment: No . . in the question there is nothing mentioned for negative energy values .. he might want to clamp it to 0 but that was answered before elsewhere. Also obviously currently it runs only once since we don't know when and how energy will be reloaded ;)

Answer (score 0):

In `Update` check if sprint axis (create a `Sprint` axis in the project input settings). Also, have a variable for how fast your energy bar drains while sprinting:

```
public float energyBarDrainRate = 1f;
private bool isSprinting = false;

void Update() { 
    isSprinting = Input.GetAxis("Sprint") > 0f;
    Vector2 mi = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
    mv = mi.normalized * speed;
}
```

Then in fixedupdate, check if your energy bar has enough to drain for that frame, and if it does then drain it and increase the effective movespeed that frame:

```
private void FixedUpdate() {
    float energyToDrain = energyBarDrainRate * Time.deltaTime
    bool drainSprint = energyAmount > energyToDrain ;
    float effectiveMv = mv;

    if (drainSprint && isSprinting) {
        effectiveMv = mv * 2f;
        energyAmount -= energyToDrain;
    }

    rb.MovePosition(rb.position + effectiveMv * Time.deltaTime);
}
```